# Getting an attribute from same level as locator using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing tests for a quite dynamic site where objects can be added and removed from a canvas in any order and for an unknown number of times. For the current test, I need to keep track of a number of objects of a specific type and then manipulate them in a specific order.

To make my life as a tester easier, the developers add a test-id to all objects, and that specifies what kind of an object it is.
In order to keep track of specific objects on the canvas, I need to get the IDs since they are unique for each object. So, what I want to do for my current test is to get a list of all objects of a specific type - using the test-id, and then retrieve the ID for each of them. The structure of each of these objects looks something like this:

```
<div test-id="object-type1" id="ember935" class=...>
  <div class="ObjectHeader">
    <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, just getting all the elements using

```
Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*[test-id=object-type1]");
```

returns a list with all the IWebElements I'm looking for. My problem is that I can't find a way of reading the id from these elements, all I can see is the nodes below. I could also create a list with all the ID's, but then I can't filter them by looking at the test-id.

Is there some way to do this without it getting messy by comparing different lists with each other or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read and print the **`id`**'s you can use the following code block :

```
IList<IWebElement> elements = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*[test-id=object-type1]");
foreach (IWebElement element in elements) 
{
    string my_id = element.GetAttribute("id");
     Console.WriteLine(my_id);
}
```

Comment: That works great! The weird thing is that it is almost exactly what I did, but for some reason my code failed. I guess the next step now is to find out where I went wrong so I don't repeat it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer but I would wrap this up in a function since you are going to be using it a lot. The function would take in the test-id as a parameter and would return the collection of the IDs for the elements specified by test-id.

BTW, the * in your CSS selector is not needed in this case.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a list of IDs that correspond to the elements of type test-id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="testId">The test-id that the elements should contain</param>
/// <returns>A list of IDs</returns>
public List<string> GetIdsByTestId(string testId)
{
    return Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector($"[test-id={testId}]")).Select(e => e.GetAttribute("id")).ToList();
}
```